# strange behavior post-commit hook

Tags: svn, post-commit, ubersvn

I want to automate publishing to my staging webserver from SVN everytime I commit a change.

The strange thing is i log in as the same user the svn server is running and run the post-commit it is working, if I commit a change the svn update is not done, but I do see a timestamp on my logging file.

```
echo `date +'%y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S'` >> /var/log/svnupdate
svn update /var/www/test >> /var/log/svnupdate
```

Is there someone who can help me?

SVN I'm using is ubersvn.

Comment: Are you aware that during the hook script no environment is set. Means no path etc. You have to use absolute path for your commands to be executed.

Comment: Can you give the exact commands you have in your post-commit hook ?

Comment: yes, i added it to my environment file, i also tested it with a absolute path, and i had no joy.

Comment: Which environment file? The problem is that SVN calls the hook script on it's own and does not look for any environment file. Just simply write absolute path to your commands ...

Comment: yep, you where right, thanks man!